# How to make jPanelMenu NOT force everything to the right?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jpanelmenu

I am using jpanelmenu everything works fine but is there a way so it wont push all the content to the right but instead over lay it

an explain would be like the Youtube's menu which is shown when you press the button next to the Youtube logo. The menu over lays everything.

Question: is there a way so it wont push all the content to the right but instead over lay it?

Got all the code from [here](http://jpanelmenu.com/)

my jpanelmenu:
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r9sLx/)

code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://jpanelmenu.com/jquery.jpanelmenu.js"></script>

        <input class="menu-trigger" type="button" value="M">

            <div class="wrap">
                <ul id="menu">
                    <li><a href="/">Overview</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#usage">Usage</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#inner-workings">Inner-Workings</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#animation">Animation</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#options">Options</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#api">API</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#tips">Tips &amp; Examples</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
                </ul>
                </div>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                var jPM = $.jPanelMenu();
                jPM.on();
            });
        </script>
        <style>
        .wrap{
            display:none;


        }
        </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        var jPM = $.jPanelMenu();
    jPM.on();

    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set [`.wrap{ position:fixed; }`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#Fixed_positioning), see my [example](http://jsfiddle.net/r9sLx/1/).